# Dynamic url for antMancher in ResouraseServerConfiger

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

How to get db data when loading the application using h2 db in  Spring Resourse configuration  and pass that data for  antMatcher and access.

Ex:
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
    System.out.println(dataSource.getConnection());
    //here i am getting db object
    http.requestMatchers().and().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/bitcash/profile/find-user**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    .antMatchers("/bitcash/profile/find-admin**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

}

please help me out of it.

public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
    System.out.println(repo.getResourse());
    System.out.println(dataSource.getConnection());

    http.requestMatchers().and().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/bitcash/profile/find-user**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    .antMatchers("/bitcash/profile/find-admin**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Web provides the following interface

```java
public interface RequestMatcher {

    boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request);

}
```

and Spring Security you can configure it using

```java
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(new MyMatcher(db), someOtherMatcher)
                .fullyAuthenticated()
```

How you implement my matcher is entirely up to you. It could be

```java
public class MyMatcher implements RequestMatcher {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String antPatternFromDB = db.getAntPattern(request);
        return new AntPathRequestMatcher(antPatternFromDB).matches(request);
    }
}
```

This assumes that `db` is a bean with access to the DB.

```java
@Bean
public Db db() {
  return new Db(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", ""));
}
```

*Please note: that instead of `DriverManager.getConnection` you should use a connection pool*. I believe that is outside the scope of this answer.